# Group Homomorphisms (some questions about what I can and can't do)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ be a group and fix some $g\in G$. Consider the map $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow G$ defined by $\phi(n)=g^n$. Show that $\phi$ is a group homomorphism.

---

Let $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$. Then,

$$\phi(a+b)=g^{a+b}$$

and

$$\phi(a)+\phi(b)=g^ag^b=g^{a+b}$$

Did I do this correctly? $\mathbb{Z}$ is a group under addition, but this doesn't work if I make $G$ a group under addition too. Am I allowed to let $G$ be a group under multiplication instead?

Comment: it should be: phi(a)*phi(b) and not +

Comment: But then I would have to have $\phi(a*b)$ as well.

Comment: If your group is abelian, you would want the map $\phi$ to send $n$ to $ng$ in order to get a group homomorphism. If your group operation is addition, you have no notion of multiplying group elements, unless, say, you are looking at the additive group of a ring.

Answer (score 2):

Note that ${\Bbb Z}$ is a specific group in which the operation is addition.  But $G$ in your question is an unspecified group in which the operation could be anything (as long as the group axioms are satisfied).  You can **write** the operation as multiplication, in which case $g\,g\,\cdots\,g$ with $n$ factors will be abbreviated to $g^n$.  But this doesn't mean that the operation **actually is** multiplication, and it certainly doesn't mean you have to take the same operation for ${\Bbb Z}$.  If you wished, you could write the operation in $G$ as addition, in which case the question would probably be stated this way:

> Consider the map $\phi:{\Bbb Z}\to G$ defined by $\phi(n)=ng$.

Remember again, this doesn't mean the operation in $G$ really is addition, it just means it's written as addition.  More abstractly (but perhaps more clearly), you could let the operation be an unspecified $*$, writing the question as

> Consider the map $\phi:{\Bbb Z}\to G$ defined by $\phi(n)=g*g*\cdots*g$, where there are $n$ factors of $g$ on the right hand side,

although this would have the drawback that if $n$ is negative it's not entirely clear what the right hand side means.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The logic here looks good (if you're looking for a proof I would make it a bit more linearly - comment down below if you want me to explain further on this).

Note that in a group there is only one operation, let's denote the operation on $G$ as $\circledast$. Now it is natural to denote
$$
g^n = \underbrace{g \circledast g \circledast \ldots \circledast g}_{n \text{ times}}
$$
similar to how in $(\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}, \cdot)$ we have
$$
r^n = \underbrace{r \cdot r \cdot \ldots \cdot r}_{n \text{ times}}
$$

The key thing to see in your group $G$, you can call the operation what ever you want, addition, multiplication, truncation, elephant-ification, nonetheless the notation above still holds.

Comment: So you would have me write it as $\phi(a+b)=g^{a+b}=g^ag^b=\phi(a)+\phi(b)$, right?

Comment: @TheMobiusLoops yep exactly! Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I just want to make sure I have shown that this is a homomorphism. I have a test coming up, and want to make sure things are straight.

Comment: @TheMobiusLoops Well implicitly there is one thing that you're missing: $\phi$ needs to be a function, in other words it needs to be well defined. So here I would say something along the lines of, if $n=m$ then it's clear that $g^n = g^m \iff \phi(n) = \phi(m)$. This is simple in this example because you can't represent elements in $\mathbb{Z}$ multiple ways but in for example $\mathbb{Z} / 5$ we have $n = n + 5k$ for any integer k.

Comment: I see, thank you. You have been very helpful.